# Scala Generics and Numeric Implicits

Tags: generics, scala, numeric, implicit

I need to pass two functions as parameters to a scala function. That function should then evaluate them and get a number from them where it will then operate on. This number can be either a Int, Double or any other numeric type. I would like the function to work, whatever the types it is working with.

The example bellow explains the issue.

```
import Numeric.Implicits._

class Arithmetic[T : Numeric](val A: Connector[T], val B: Connector[T]) {
  val sum  = new Connector({ A.value + B.value })
}

class Constant[T](var x: T) {
  val value = new Connector({ x })
}

class Connector[T](f: => T) {
  def value: T = f
  override def toString = value.toString()
}

object Main extends App{
  val n1 = new Constant(1)

  // works
  val n5 = new Constant(5)
  val a = new Arithmetic( n1.value, n5.value )
  println(a.sum)

 // no works
 val n55 = new Constant(5.5)
 val b = new Arithmetic( n1.value, n55.value )
 println(b.sum)

}
```

I've also tried

```
class Arithmetic[T,R : Numeric](val A: Connector[T], val B: Connector[R]) {
```

and several other combinations, but I ended up with

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: scala.math.Numeric[Any]
val sum  = new Connector({ A.value + B.value })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is because  `Numeric[T].plus` can only be used to add two values of the *same type* `T`.
Your code is written under the assumption that numeric widening happens automatically - which will not in this case as the compiler does not know anything about the types except that there exists a `Numeric[T]` instance.

If you need `sum` to be a stable value, you will have to provide the necessary type information in the constructor like this:

```
class Arithmetic[A : Numeric, R <% A, S <% A](val a: Connector[R], b: Connector[S]) {
  val sum = new Connector[A]((a.value:A) + (b.value:A))
}
```

This requires types `R`  and `S` to be convertible into some type `A` for which a `Numeric[A]` istance is known.
When creating an instance you would always have to provide all type parameters as they cannot be inferred.

If you do not need `sum` to be stable you could change your class to this:

```
class Arithmetic[A,B](val a: Connector[A], val b: Connector[B]) {

  // if A and B are the same types
  def sum(implicit e: B =:= A, n: Numeric[A]): Connector[A] =
    new Connector(n.plus(a.value, b.value))

  // else widen to C
  def wideSum[C](implicit f: A => C, g: B => C, n: Numeric[C]) =
    new Connector(n.plus(a.value, b.value))
}

val a = new Connector(1)

val b = new Connector(2)

val c = new Connector(3.0)

val d = (new Arithmetic(a,b)).sum

// val e = (new Arithmetic(b,c)).sum // <-- does not compile

val e = (new Arithmetic(b,c)).wideSum[Double]
```

When widening you will still have to provide the type information though.

Comment: does your first solution works? The compiler will complain that b.value should be a String.

Comment: @Moritz, while your second suggestion works, I'm still obligated to insert the type when they differ. That will not work as I won't know in the future what types are arriving at Arithmetic. It should be automatic, just like when you write 2 + 4.1 in REPL and get 6.1.

Comment: @Moritz, as for your first suggestion, I was unable to make it work also. the error: ambiguous implicit values:
both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type object scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral
and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type object scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral
match expected type Numeric[A]
val a = new Arithmetic( n1.value, n5.value ), where n1 and n5 are constants.

Comment: @HugoSFerreira, @tiagoboldt: if you use the first example you have to provide *all* type parameters to when constructing the instance, e.g.: `new Arithmetic[Double,Int,Double](intConn, dblConn)` as they cannot be inferred.

Comment: @HugoSFerreira did you forget the `import Numeric.Implicits._`?

Comment: @Moritz Yes, that was it... It's unfortunate that one needs to specify all the types (after all, the last two can be easily inferred).

Comment: @Moritz I can see that I will always have to explicitly specify the type(s) at some point. That really disappointed. I'll accept your answer then, tks :)